# Open Maps for Navigation from PhoneGapp

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-build

I have a PhoneGap app in which I want to allow users to click on a link to open maps so they can navigate to a location.

I am using this code snippet that I discovered on Stack:

```
<ahref=geo:38.715362,-75.086898> Navigate </a>
```

On Android when I click that link, it opens an option for me to choose a navigation option to open it it. I can choose Google Maps, Waze etc.

Side note, in Android when I open with google maps, it just moves to that location doesn't add a balloon for me to click on to navigate to. But Waze works perfectly.

My brother just tested my iPhone version of the app and when he clicks the link it does not open anything at all. Any ideas how to make this work on iPhone too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Cordova plugins that allow you to launch the native maps for navigation:

- https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator
- https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-directions

But you need to call a function on the click/tap event, something like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="launchnavigator.navigate(params)"> Navigate </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without using a plugin you can use the magic "maps" protocol on iOS. For example:

```
<a href="maps:daddr=38.715362,-75.086898">Navigate</a>
```